# Why UIButton uses Target Action Design Pattern not Delegate Pattern and Vice Versa for UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uitextfielddelegate, target-action

Can any one help in understanding why Apple decides to uses Target Action design pattern for event handling of UIButton not Delegate Pattern?

Or, I can say why Apple choose delegation Design pattern for UITextField even same thing can be achieved by Target Action also.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41141828/why-uibutton-uses-target-action-design-pattern-not-delegate-pattern-and-vice-ver

Answer (score 2):

There are various trade-offs to the different approaches. I think the clincher for button actions, though, is that you can add multiple target/actions to a button. (A one-to-many relationship.) Delegation is a one-to-one relationship, so having a button trigger multiple actions, possibly to different targets, would not be possible with the delegation design pattern.

I think if Apple were designing button handling now they'd use blocks/closures instead of IBActions. The control could hold an array of blocks and the events that trigger each.

Answer (score 1):

All `@IBAction` functions have one of three signatures;

- `functionName() -> Void`
- `functionName(sender: Any) -> Void`
- `functionName(sender: Any, forEvent event: UIEvent) -> Void`

An IBAction cannot accept any other arguments and does not return a value.

A delegate allows the use of functions that take different parameters and return values while actions are a standard approach across `UIView` subclasses.

In some classes, such as `UITextField`, certain action can be handled through both delegate and action methods. I guess this just gives you some choice; if you are already implementing delegate functions then you don't need to implement action handlers as well.

Comment: Actually, there are **THREE** valid function signatures for an IBAction: no parameters, a sender, or a sender and the triggering `UIEvent`. (`@IBAction func doSomething()`, 
`@IBAction func doSomething(sender: UIButton)`, and 
`@IBAction func doSomething(sender: UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent)`) See listing 1 in this link: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrol

Comment: Thanks.  I have edited my answer.  Interestingly Apple's documentation is incorrect; the sender may not be a UIButton

Comment: The sender can indeed be a `UIButton`. I do that all the time. The `UIControl` class is the parent class of UIButton, so a UIButton *is* a `UIControl`.

Comment: Yes, the sender *can* be a `UIButton` but it doesn't *have* to be a `UIButton`.  The signature in Objective-C is `id sender`, so in fact, the Swift signature is AnyObject/Any

Comment: Yup. IB defaults to making the sender in an action `id` in Obj-C, and `Any` in Swift, which I find annoying. I almost always want it to be the specific class of the sending control.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to Apple wanting to show different patterns in code.